# Nativescript + Genymotion : App not starting up on simulator - Execution failed for task ':buildMetadata'

Tags: java, android, telerik, genymotion, nativescript

Im running form the CLI

$ tns debug android --geny "Custom Phone - 5.0.0 - API21 - 768x1280" --debug-brk

> Multiple devices found! Starting debugger on emulator. If you want to
>   debug on specific device please select device with --device option.
>   Executing before-prepare hook from
>   /Users/mohit/work/Mobile/native/Groceries/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
>   Found peer TypeScript 1.8.10 Project successfully prepared (android)
>
> :config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles     +found plugins:
>   tns-core-modules-widgets
>
> :config phase:  createPluginsConfigFile    Creating product flavors
>   include.gradle file in
>   /Users/mohit/work/Mobile/native/Groceries/platforms/android/configurations
>   folder...
>
> :config phase:  pluginExtend  +applying configuration from:
>   /Users/mohit/work/Mobile/native/Groceries/platforms/android/configurations/include.gradle
>     +applying configuration from:
>   /Users/mohit/work/Mobile/native/Groceries/platforms/android/configurations/tns-core-modules-widgets/include.gradle
>
> :config phase:  copyAarDependencies
>
> :config phase:  addAarDependencies    +adding dependency:
>   /Users/mohit/work/Mobile/native/Groceries/platforms/android/libs/aar/widgets-release.aar
>   Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature. :preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :preF0DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :checkF0DebugManifest
>   :preF0ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareGroceriesRuntimeUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareWidgetsReleaseLibrary UP-TO-DATE :prepareF0DebugDependencies
>   :compileF0DebugAidl UP-TO-DATE :compileF0DebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :generateF0DebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :cleanLocalAarFiles
>   :ensureMetadataOutDir :collectAllJars :setProperties
>   :asbg:generateInterfaceNamesList :asbg:runAstParser UP-TO-DATE
>   :asbg:generateBindings UP-TO-DATE :mergeF0DebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :compileF0DebugShaders UP-TO-DATE :generateF0DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :mergeF0DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :generateF0DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :generateF0DebugResources UP-TO-DATE :mergeF0DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :processF0DebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :processF0DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :generateF0DebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :incrementalF0DebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :compileF0DebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE :compileF0DebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :compileF0DebugSources UP-TO-DATE :buildMetadata Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.animated.BuildConfig conflict:
>   /Users/mohit/work/Mobile/native/Groceries/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/animated-vector-drawable/24.2.1/jars/classes.jar
>   and
>   /Users/mohit/work/Mobile/native/Groceries/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/animated-vector-drawable/23.4.0/jars/classes.jar
>     at com.telerik.metadata.ClassRepo.cacheJarFile(ClassRepo.java:21)   at
>   com.telerik.metadata.Builder.build(Builder.java:39)   at
>   com.telerik.metadata.Generator.main(Generator.java:44) :buildMetadata
>   FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':buildMetadata'.
>
>   > Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
>   >     finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 11.293 secs Command
>   /Users/mohit/work/Mobile/native/Groceries/platforms/android/gradlew
>   failed with exit code 1

How do I fix this ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Most probably this issue has been related to genymotion emulator. You can setup AVD Emulator - https://github.com/NativeScript/docs/blob/master/tooling/android-virtual-devices.md and then try to start the debugging option using 'tns debug <platform_name>' or use the instructions here - https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/visual-studio-code-extension#debugging , where has been shown how to use debugger via VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

```
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android
```

https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/339